# base64 mp3 to web audio api

Tags: javascript, audio, cross-platform

I have a lot of base64 mp3 like "data:audio/mpeg;base64...." and i want to play it with web audio api in computer and mobile. With  I can play it normally, but it's quite limited so i want to use web audio api. but i can only make it to computer, not mobile

I tried to use decodeAudioData() but it said it's not ArrayBuffer.

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'AudioContext': invalid ArrayBuffer for audioData.

I guess it's because my base64 is a mp3 compressed format, and this function only can deal with decompressed data. So i try XMLHttpRequest to load my base64 mp3 first. It works in computer, but not mobile
Is there a way to make web audio api play "data:audio/mpeg;base64...." in mobile?

Comment: just an observation - why would you send base64 encoded data from the server? base64 is 33% larger than binary! and your issues isn't because it's compressed mp3, your issue is because you probably are trying to send base64 text to the audio pipeline, rather than mp3

Comment: I am using swiffy for a flash project, with lots of sound in lots of swf. swiffy convert sound to base64 so i need to deal with base64